# set dynamic UIWebView as header in TableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uitableview, uiwebview

I set the UIwebview as a header in `UITableview`.`UIWebview` height and width are dynamic.Its come for local html files.

`UIWebview` and `UITableview` are under one scroll.

It works fine for iphone.Same method I wrote for ipad  it works good.but one problem is there.
In ipad Header view and table view alignment is not proper .

Here is code.

Rootviewcotrollor is `UITableviewControllor`

Rootviewcontroller.m

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
self.title = @"Webview in UITableView";
webview = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 10)]; // Don't use CGRectZero here, won't work
webview.delegate = self;
webview.hidden = YES;

[webview loadRequest:[[NSURLRequest alloc] 
                      initWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com/"]]];

[self.tableView setTableHeaderView:webview]; // Leave this, else you'll have rows to fill the rest of the screen
```

}

```
- (void) webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
float newSize = [[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.documentElement.scrollHeight"] floatValue];
NSLog(@"Resizing webview from %.2f to %.2f", webView.frame.size.height, newSize);
webView.frame = CGRectMake(webView.frame.origin.x, webView.frame.origin.y, webView.frame.size.width, newSize);
webView.hidden = NO;

// We need to reset this, else the new frame is not used.
[self.tableView setTableHeaderView:webview];
```

}

For same code iphone output

[image]

And iPad output `UITableview` start slider ahead of the `UIWebview.`

[image]

I try to set frame of header but it's not working,it give webview and table view both have it's own scrollview which not needed.

What is solution for it?

Thank you.

Comment: Start the webview from a later position like CGRectMake(30,0,your.width,your.height)

Comment: I tried it but whole frames are disturbed and both have their own scroll.

Comment: Try taking a simple UITableView and if you want an outline around them , you can do it by using cell.layer.borderwidth=1.0f; but firstly import QuartzCore framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a grouped table view that's why its alignment is not proper cause grouped table view takes some default size from x-origin and y-origin always... you can use plain table or set x of grouped table or increase x-origin of web view..

Comment: how can i set x and y origin for grouped table? you see ,for iphone it's ok but in ipad it's not proper align.

Comment: It also disturbed frame and both have their own scroll.I need both in one scroll.

Comment: stop the scrolling of webview... disable the web-view scrolling

Comment: It's working. I just disable scrolling of web-view and set table header frame and table-view frame again.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this in your "`webviewdidfinishedload`" delegate
note that "`MyWebView"` is the webview that fires the delegate also "`webViewHeight`" is int value that after it you should add your custom control and it's declared as public this is snap from my working code.. that add uitableview after webview to add comments.

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    CGSize size = [MyWebView sizeThatFits: CGSizeMake(1.0f, 1.0f)]; // Pass any size here
    CGRect frame = MyWebView.frame;
    frame.size.height = size.height;
    MyWebView.frame = frame;
    webViewHeight = size.height + 200;
}
```

Comment: can you log the frame.size.height and get values...just need to get what the problem exactly to know how to fix it..